# SQL - Looking to show when 2 columns combined have the same data

Tags: sql, duplicates, sybase

I have a database table that has a Vendor_ID column and a Vendor_Item column.

```
Vendor_id   Vendor_item
101          111
101          111
101          123
```

I need a way to show when vendor_id and vendor_item are combined, show if having count greater than 1. The vendor_item number can be in there multiple times as long as it has a different vendor_id.

```
Vendor_id   Vendor_item
101          111       
101          111
```

I have done the following but it only shows results have have more than 1 and doesn't show both records like the above example.

```
SELECT vendor_id,vendor_item
From Inventory_master 
group by vendor_id,vendor_item
having count(*) >1
```

If possible I would like a way to add another column ( UPC ) to the results. The system I am working on can import back into the system with UPC so I would be able to fix what is duplicated.

```
Vendor_id   Vendor_item     UPC
101          111            456 
101          111            789
```

Comment: you should also explain where the values for `upc` are coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the `UPC` column as from where and how you are getting it but you can change your existing query a bit like below to get the desired data

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory_master WHERE vendor_item IN (
SELECT vendor_item 
From Inventory_master 
group by vendor_item 
having count(vendor_item) >1);
```

Comment: I've never used Sybase, but shouldn't there be a `WHERE` before the `vendor_item IN` ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, LOL ... nice catch. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks...That gave me the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery and then JOIN back to the inventory_master table:

```
SELECT im.*
FROM
  Inventory_master im INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vendor_id, vendor_item
    From Inventory_master 
    group by vendor_id,vendor_item
    having count(*) >1) s
  ON im.vendor_id = s.vendor_id AND im.vendor_item = s.vendor_item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from(
select vendor_id,vendor_item, count(*) over (partition by vendor_id) cnt
from Inventory_master
) where cnt>1
```

Comment: If the `partition by` were correct, this would be the best answer.